# Proxmox - Port forwarding from Host to Guest

Tags: linux, networking, proxmox, guest

I'll just quickly start by apologising due to my lack of knowledge in Linux networking and I appreciate all the help I'll receive from any patient users willing to help a newbie. I have a Linux (Debian Wheezy Proxmox-VE) installation setup on my dedicated machine from Hetzner.de. I have been trying hard to port forward to a Guest VM (Windows Server 2008).

It seems that no matter what changes I make to the /etc/network/interfaces file it seems to stop the internet working on the host after reboot, therefore I have to access the KVM of the host to revert the changes to restore the internet.

My current working interfaces file is as shown:

```
# network interface settings auto lo iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
        address  88.198.51.248
        netmask  255.255.255.224
        gateway  88.198.51.225
        broadcast  88.198.51.255
        up route add -net 10.0.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0
        up route add -net 88.198.51.224 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 88.198.51.225 eth0
# default route to access subnet

iface vmbr0 inet manual
        address  10.0.2.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

My guest IP is 10.0.2.15 and is currently set to NAT. I have researched through many Proxmox threads and have also looked on [Proxmox - single public ip with multiple vms, openvz containers work, kvm's don't have a route](https://serverfault.com/questions/532938/proxmox-single-public-ip-with-multiple-vms-openvz-containers-work-kvms-don) however I can't seem to use the same interfaces and edit the IPs and parameters to my own according host.

I also have my own post on Proxmox forum that show my attempts and research further just to show that I have really tried and that the research effort required is met: http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/17992-Port-forwarding-host-to-guest-

I've tried all I can and I really hope I can get some help. Many thanks!

Comment: Any help in this? Me too need now, have a Dedicated server and i need to port forward to my vms